# Recover files that were opend on a usb drive after it is removed

Tags: excel, ms-office, data-recovery, tally

I'm trying to recover few files which a guy must have opened on my system using his USB after he removed the USB drive.
I can see under 'AppData->Roaming->Microsoft->Office' has a shortcut of that file with the same name. Is it possible to recover the data of that file?

PS: Don't judge me.

Comment: I suspect not.  But the question is off topic for SO so you should delete it and maybe post on [tag:SuperUser]